# setting function pointers C

Tags: c

I have a simple question:
Let's supose that I have a function called `_foo`.

```
void _foo (void *, void *, int);
```

Now, I want to create a new `struct` that holds a ponter to `_foo`, so:

```
struct _st {
    struct _st *next;
    void (*action)(void *, void *, int);
};
```

And then I initialize one `struct _st` variable:

```
struct _st test = {0x0, _foo};
```

My question is: is there a way that I can set `test.action` whithout being by the name of the function? I mean, a fixed address or something like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test.action` is a pointer you can set it to any address (numeric address e.g. `0x2000`) you want, `_foo` is also a symbolic name for an address. However for doing that you need to keep in mind the following points:

- You should typecast it properly to suppress compiler warning/error.
- Be cautious about the undefined behavior you may invoke by accessing some address not accessible to you including dreaded SEGFAULT runtime error.
- It is always sensible to use symbolic names/constants for such assignments to help you understand your own code in future as why did you assigned it, how can you easily modify it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an address only if you set that address through the linker. Otherwise, the name is pretty much the only reference you have to that function.

Comment: what if I had `const char *tst2 = "_foo";`. Is there a way to set `test.action` using `tst2`?

Comment: no, those are two completely different things. You could be playing tricks with the compiler (and that would really depend on the compiler you are using), but this is not one of them.

Comment: @LuizEduardoF. I dont think thats possible on `C`

Comment: @LuizEduardoF. You could read the symbol table of your program (if it hasn't been stripped) to find the address of the symbol given by that string ... but that's an awful thing to do. Your question should state what You're *really* trying to do.